# Grub rescue problem after formatting windows partion

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

Hie,I have just switched to Ubuntu,and have installed Ubuntu 13.10 along with windows 7.At installation time i just gave 15gb to Ubuntu,later on i decided to give my one of partition E:/ to Ubuntu ,so deleted it and formatted it to ext4 through some disk application named "Disks" in Ubuntu.But this suddenly creates a lot problem to me.

1. Formatted partition is not being mounted.
   and prompt with following lines appear:

   ```
   Error creating partition on /dev/sda:
    Command-line `parted-align optimal-script "/dev/sda" mkpart logical ext2 384777Mib 479045091327b"exited with non zero exit status 1:
   Error:You requested a partition from 403GB to 479GB.
    The closest location we can manage is 403GB to 479GB.(udisk-error-quark,0)
   ```
2. When i rebooted system i have following error:

   ```
   Filesystem unknown
   entering in rescue mode
   grub rescue>:
   ```

   Which i solved with following commands

   ```
   set prefix=(hd0,msdos7)/boot/grub
   set root=(hd0,msdos7)
   insmod normal
   normal
   ```
3. But now every time i boot system i have to type these commands manually.

Somebody help me out .Please!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have booted using the commands

```
set prefix=(hd0,msdos7)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,msdos7)
insmod normal
normal
```

open a terminal using (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and enter your password. This will update the partitions and inform grub which partitions to search for while booting.

Comment: That is working absolutely fine with grub problem, :) but Is there anyway of my mounting error?(Problem 1) I'm hopeless in that ..

Comment: You should probably post it as a different question, you may get a better response.